# Printing slides via lpr: How to get 4-up in landscape correctly?

Tags: pdf, printer, printing, lpr

If I have some pages of text, I can use `lpr -o sides=one-sided -o landscape -o number-up=4 -o number-up-layout=btlr -o fitplot -P myprinter` to print the text 4-up landscape. The layout is

```
----------
| 1    2 |
| 3    4 |
----------
```

Now if I have a .pdf document generated via `pdflatex` from the code...

```
\documentclass[
paper=128mm:96mm,
pagesize% has no influence on the problem
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[bottom=4mm, left=5mm, top=5mm, right=5mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Page 1 \clearpage Page 2 \clearpage Page 3 \clearpage Page 4
\end{document}
```

... the printer prints it in portrait format like this:

```
--------
| 2  4 |
|      |
| 1  3 | 
--------
```

I am wondering what I can specify so that the printer knows it should rotate each of the four 'subpages' by 90 degrees?

Note that this has been asked previously on [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109820/printing-slides-via-lpr-how-to-get-4-up-in-landscape-correctly?noredirect=1#comment240994_109820) but it was recommended to ask it here since this most likely is not a problem of the way the .pdf is generated.

Comment: I'd probably use `pdfpages` to set up a document as needed and print that. Have a look at `pdfjam`; maybe it does what you need.